# Create a new table in SQL based on two other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, create-table

I have two tables against which I would like to create new table with the output.

For example;

Table 1

```
Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
a               b          c
```

Table 2

```
Column 4    Column5     Column6
D              E           F
```

I've joined above tables with an "Union". Not sure how to create a new table from the original query itself

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: As per the question guide, please show us what you have tried and what research you have carried out.

Comment: What's your expected result? I think that `UNION` with `INSERT INTO .... SELECT` might be worked as your expected

Comment: We would like to help you but not sure where did you stuck at problem.

Comment: Perhaps you use the terminology in manner that obscures your goal. Generally speaking we try to avoid duplicating data for good reasons. So why do you need to create yet another table that combines the contents of two existing tables? Perhaps a view will serve just as well. Is your reference to "table" driven by a need to pull information into your application via a datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for creating *a new table*, use `INTO` statement that provide a new table. it should be place in the first select

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3
INTO   newtable --creating new table
FROM   table1
UNION
SELECT column4,
       column5,
       column6
FROM   table2
```

If you have created *a New Table*, then use `INSERT INTO` Statement

```
INSERT INTO newtable
            (column1,
             column2,
             column3)
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       column3
FROM   table1
UNION
SELECT column4,
       column5,
       column6
FROM   table2
```